# Manage android application and service

Tags: android

How do I manage all the application and service that have installed into the android device? I want to uninstall the apps. I've look into the docs of android and found no article about how to do it? Anyone can suggest a direction and API? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to uninstall the apps.

This is not possible from a standard SDK application.

Comment: So how can I do that? I see some uninstall apps can do. Like this (https://market.android.com/details?id=com.rhythm.hexise.uninst&feature=search_result)

Comment: @Magic: If you want to launch the built-in application uninstaller, use [`ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE)

Comment: Thanks. But I don't want the build-in. I want to manage by myself.